# Constrain allowed children in React TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Using TypeScript in a React project is there any way to enforce some constraints on the allowed children of a component? Compile-time is preferred, but run-time could still be helpful.

In my case I have a component, call it `<ClickTracker>`, and it expects a single child with a callback prop `onClick` and it adds some extra functionality to the callback (tracking the click in an external library).

This works great as long as the child inside a `<ClickTracker>` does actually make use of an `onClick` prop (all HTML elements implement this, for example), but fails silently otherwise.

For example, this works:

```
<ClickTracker>
  <div>Hello</div>
</ClickTracker>
```

But this doesn't work:

```
class Hello extends Component<{}, {}> {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello</div>
  } 
}

<ClickTracker>
  <Hello />
</ClickTracker>
```

But this does work because it passes `onClick` to an HTML element:

```
class Hello extends Component<{onClick: MouseEventHandler}, {}> {
  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>Hello</div>
  } 
}

<ClickTracker>
  <Hello />
</ClickTracker>
```

As you can see I would like to have some safety around what can go inside `<ClickTracker>` based on the child props. Or if there's another way this could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently, no possible way of enforcing the children type with TypeScript.

There is more information in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4833).

Answer (score 1):

> Or if there's another way this could be done

Click events bubble up unless some component stopped propogation (not the default behavior for native components). So you can:

```
<div onClick={()=>alert('still noted')}>
  <Hello />
</div>
```

And that div is your `ClickTracker`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, upvoted. In my case adding a wrapping `<div>` is not acceptable in all cases. I guess I could use the pattern where you specify the wrapping tag type, but that's pretty annoying because it requires you to understand the rendered tree just to use this functional component, and again you get no errors until runtime. Maybe there's a way to make it smart by inspecting the child and using the appropriate HTML wrapper element?